# NullPointerException в Android 7.0

Tags: java, android

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:760)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:831)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:791)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:173)
   at com.knowledgecity.common.BaseActivity.onBackPressed(BaseActivity.java:131)
   at com.knowledgecity.activity.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:322)
   at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2854)
   at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3346)
```

Данная ошибка появляется в Android 7.0. При просмотре видео. В остальных версиях все нормально. В чем проблема?

Comment: Судя по логу, при нажатии на кнопку "назад".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Есть ли какой нить эмулятор Android 7.0?

Comment: @EraNewGames конечно, в студии через AVDmanager можно настроить под любую версию

Comment: Она запускается полтора часа

Comment: @EraNewGames, студия или эмулятор? Мне кажется вы отстали от жизни :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Конечно отстал, Я жи на AMD Сижу   ^<>^. А вы небось на Intele или на Mace вообще?)

Comment: @EraNewGames, ваш AMD виртуализацию не поддерживает?

Comment: Есть. Все равно тупит. 6 ядерный проц. SSD даже. Виртулацизя включена.

Может что - то надо скачать от Гугла? Google APIs или что - то типо того?